# Access URL with params Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-router

I have a route with params like `{path: 'Client/:id', component: ClientComponent}`
When I try to access the url ...Client/123, I get an exception "`Cannot match any routes 123`". It happens when I load the page with url ...Client/123 .
When I try to access the url while using my app and navigate from one url to another, everything is ok. It happens only if I load client page first.

Any ideas why? Thank you.

> Router version is 3.0.0-alpha.7

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you run into this issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9460

This one might be related https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9483